# Bard in react-native

Tags: react-native, data-science, artificial-intelligence, alphabet, chatgpt-api

**Can I implement Bard in react-native project?**

I searched on Google and chatGPT as well to find that can use BardAPI in react-native project, so I didn't find any article or any things related to this. Could anyone explain me the way of implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Not Yet . You have to request for API access and once you have the access then you can do it.

Here is the link for access requests  : https://makersuite.google.com/waitlist